# .htaccess file returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have something that is wrong in my .htaccess but I can't seem to figure out what.
This my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: There is a space char in your flags between L and QSA  `[L, QSA]` remove it to see if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have it your htaccess Rules file in this way, there are few things which I have fixed in this file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule !(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: @user15270366, Could you please do let me know if my answer worked for you?